# JAX-RS application not returns Dates in millis in WAS Liberty

Tags: java, date, serialization, jax-rs, websphere

Good afternoon, I created a javax.ws.rs.core.Application and it returns Date objects in milliseconds with Wildfly. Since i recently had to switch to IBM Websphere Liberty, I noticed that now Dates are returned in Timestamp format.
I tried to add this ContextResolver:

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>
{
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JacksonConfig() throws Exception
    {
        SerializationConfig serConfig = mapper.getSerializationConfig();
        serConfig.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig = mapper.getDeserializationConfig();
        deserializationConfig.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);  }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0)
    {
        return mapper;
    }
 }
```

and added this class to my application, but it seems not working.
I suspect I may have misunderstood something... ;)

Comment: Hi @Kava - what version of Liberty and what version of jaxrs feature are you using? The jaxrs-2.0 feature uses a forked version of Jackson for most JSON-Object serialization, but jaxrs-2.1 uses JSON-B (which might be an alternative for you). Also are you packaging Jackson in your app? And do you have an Application subclass in your app - if so, are you including the JacksonConfig class in the getClasses or getSingletons method?

Comment: Hi @AndyMcCright I'm using Liberty 19.0.0.12. Jaxrs 2.1 and I am packaging jackson in my app. Moreover I confirm that I am adding my JacksoConfig to my  Application adding the class in the same way I add my services. Tx

Comment: Most likely Jackson (which is the default JAX-RS provider with Wildfly) is not being used as the JSON provider. You should add the Jackson-jaxrs-json-providers dependency and then register the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class. Just adding Jackson library is not enough. You need the JAX-RS provider.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Paul Samsotha, it was enough to register the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class

Thanks